# Android NDK Error std -std=gnu++11

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

When I compile my Android ndk project I have this error:

```
C:/Users/User/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO
C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

My current android ndk version is: android-r9 
My queston is:

**Why I get this error?**

I have tryed to compile in Android studio and Eclipse with the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually specifiy `-std=c++11` anywhere?